# Reset button does not clear fields in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reset

I have a page which reads from a file and displays filtered results depending on what is entered in the search boxes. When I click the reset button it clears the search boxes which is what I want, but I also want the filtered results to be cleared too. If I uncomment the call below, which is commented at the moment - it works but the search boxes do not clear.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <ul data-bind="foreach:properties">
        <li><input data-bind="attr:{placeholder:id},event:{change:$root.onInputChange}, value:value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></li>
    </ul>   
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    <!--<input type="reset" value="Reset" data-bind="click:$root.onclick"/>-->
</form>
<p></p>
<table data-bind="foreach:itemsFiltered">
    <tr data-bind="foreach:$parent.formatItem($data)">
        <td data-bind="text:value"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need the search boxes and filtered results to clear.

Answer (score 8):

Resetting a form resets the fields in it back to their default values (as specified by the `value` attribute). It doesn't clear the fields unless the default values are blank.

Your JavaScript is setting `value` attributes.

If you want to blank the fields, you'll need to set their `value` **property** to an empty string instead of simply resetting the form.